# Delete dynamically a element in listview and custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

It's the first time i'm posting here. I've got a way to delete dynamically a element in my list on checking a box. But checkbox or button, every time i try to delete a element above a other one, the other takes the click too and .. surprisingly don't delete but become undeletable.

Here's my onClickListener of my checkbox :

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class onCheckboxClickListener extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Task card;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public onCheckboxClickListener(Task card, CheckBox checkBox) {
        this.card = card;
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        tasks.remove(card);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I'm sorry to have posted uselessly here.

I've forgotten to add the listener back in the viewHolder in the getView() method. The error wasn't in this piece of code.

Hoping it'll help someone in the future. :)